# Как сделать параметризированный запрос перед FROM с помощью Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net, dapper

Пишу код для получения максимального порядка колонки. Хочу защититься от SQL-инъекций. Для этого хочу сделать tableName параметризированным. Но возникает ошибка синтаксиса. Подскажите как сделать чтобы параметризация в FROM работала.

```html
var maxColumnOrderSql = $"SELECT MAX("Order") FROM @{nameof(tableName)}";
var maxColumnOrder = await Connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int?>(maxColumnOrderSql, new { tableName });
```

Вот так выглядит таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю как в постгре, но вообще можно проверить существование таблицы в чем то типа `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` передав в этот запрос `tableName` как параметр. И если такое имя существует - смело использовать его напрямую.

Comment: Параметры нельзя использовать для имён таблиц. Поэтому придётся оставить конкатенацию строк. Для безопасности делать какие-либо проверки, что передаётся именно имя таблицы, а не что-то левое.

Comment: У Вас много таких таблиц?